# How to stop default behaviour of modal element in carbon-design components "by clicking outside of the modal it closes"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

I am using data attributes to use modal in react through `carbon-components` but the previous solution on bootstrap does not work.

Like:

```
data-backdrop="static"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Your own 

research and code attempts are expected. Edit the question to include your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and 

Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of carbon-components consists a demo which will show you the events which is fired in the demo page.

[Modal Demo](http://react.carbondesignsystem.com/?selectedKind=Modal&selectedStory=Default&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel)

The event is called `onRequestClose` which will get fired if clicked on the close button or out side the modal. The event returns the event object which you could check for the target and use `preventDefault()` to stop closing the modal.

Please refer to events [here](https://www.carbondesignsystem.com/components/modal/code) for an example on how to stop closing the modal.

Sample code for the example :

```
document.addEventListener('modal-beinghidden', function(evt) {
  if (myApplication.shouldModalKeptOpen(evt.target)) {
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: can u please explain if I use the data attributes approach like <button data-modal-target = "# modal-Id"><div  data-modal className="bx--modal"></div> then where can I use the event? there is no available event named onRequestClose when I use this approach to add listener

Answer (score 0):

Try using `preventCloseOnClickOutside` and set it to `true`.